# Write (or copy) the contents of one bytes.Buffer to another

Tags: go, writer

I have 2 `bytes.Buffer` instances. I want to copy the results from the second (let's call it `src`) to the first one (`dst`)

Apparently `io.Copy` method does not work in this case since it requires an `io.Writer` interface and `bytes.Buffer` does not implement the corresponding method.

Same goes for the `io.CopyBuffer` method.

What is the most appropriate way of just copying the contents of one `bytes.Buffer` to another?

Comment: `io.Copy(&dst, &src)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
dst.Write(src.Bytes())
```

to write all of the bytes in `src` to `dst` where `src` and `dst` are a `*bytes.Buffer` or a `bytes.Buffer`.

Comment: In case somebody wants just to create a copy, `dst := bytes.NewBuffer(src.Bytes())` will do

Comment: @DavidLilue that only copies the slice (view), but does not copy the data. `src.Bytes()` aliases the underlying storage for `src` by returning a slice pointing to the same backing array, and `bytes.NewBuffer` expects to own its argument. This will cause trouble if either `src` or `dst` is written to: https://go.dev/play/p/VvbOGH7Jm0a .

Either use `dst.Write` (which performs a `copy(..)` on your behalf into `dst.Buf`) or, if you want to use NewBuffer, use something like `dst := bytes.NewBuffer(append([]byte{}, src.Bytes()...))`.

See also: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

Comment: One reason that aliasing the storage might appear to work is the bytes.Buffer makes a copy of its data if it grows the backing storage (in turn, unaliasing the array). However, if there's extra capacity in the array, it'll be used before growing. So maybe a more compelling example is: https://go.dev/play/p/72YxTgeXQnb

Comment: @SethP thanks for the clarification. The documentation is also clear about it: _The new Buffer takes ownership of buf, and the caller should not use buf after this call_. `buf` being the byte slice. Not sure how I missed that. The problem I was solving didn't alter the `src` slice after copying (just for reading). So for me, it was enough with the shallow copy.

Answer (score -1):

`bytes.Buffer` does implement `io.Writer`, but only if it is a pointer:

```
package main
import "bytes"

func main() {
   a := bytes.NewBufferString("hello world")
   b := new(bytes.Buffer)
   b.ReadFrom(a)
   println(b.String())
}
```

https://godocs.io/bytes#Buffer.Write

Comment: If you do this, you can't call `Read` on `a` again.